# Tab alighnment and color HTML

Tags: html

I am having some issues with my html. I have created two white sub tabs underneath the main tabs. The problem is I want it to be white not just for the sub tabs, but all across so there is the appearance of a white bar beneath the parent tabs above it.

This is the code for the sub tabs.

```html
 <ul id="tabnav2">
    <li class = "tab1"><a href="html.htm">HTML</a></li>
    <li class = "tab1"><a href="googledocs.htm">Google Docs</a></li>
 </ul>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
ul#tabnav2 
{ /*effects all tabs as if they are a unit*/
font: bold 15px ,sans-serif, arial, verdana; 
padding-left: 5px; 
margin: 1; 
}

#tabnav2 a 
{   /*effects the text contents of the tab*/
text-align: center; 
display: block; 
color: #003D99;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px;
}

ul#tabnav2 li
{
float:left;
height: 21px;
width: 120px;
background-color: #FFF;
} 

#tabnav2 a:hover 
{   
background: #000052;
color: #fff;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle rather than posting your code.

Comment: You closed with a </div> instead of </ul>. Idk if this is the answer though, but fix that first and see if it is.